# A Prolog programme getting ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have created a program, `list(X,Y)` to check whether all the elements in list Y are smaller than X.

The codes are as follows.

```
list(X,[]).
list(X,[Y|Z]):-X>Y,list(X,Z).
```

It works fine when I type `list(3,[1,2])`. However, if I type `list(3,Y`) in order to find lists which only contain elements smaller than 3, there is an error.

```
?- list(3,[1,2]).
true .

?- list(3,Y).
Y = [] ;
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I have read some posts which got the same error, but I still don't understand which part of my codes goes wrong.

Here comes a similar example found from internet.
`greater(X,Y,Z)` returns the part `Z` of `Y` that is greater than `X`.

```
greater(X,[],[]).
greater(X,[H|Y],[H|Z]) :- H>X, greater(X,Y,Z).
greater(X,[H|Y],Z) :- H=<X, greater(X,Y,Z).


?- greater(2,[1,2,3], Y).
Y = [3].
```

The question is, what is the difference between the codes of `greater(X,Y,Z)` and `list(X,Y)` so that there is no error when calling `greater(2,[1,2,3], Y).`.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: When using `>`, all arguments must be instantiated. So when you inquired `list(3,Y)`, your `list` clause attempted `3 > Y` (`Y` not bound) and yields the error. What did you want `list(3, Y)` to mean given the definition you have stated in your post? If you want it to generate lists meeting your criteria (for which there are an infinite number of solutions), then you will need a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I only want list Y to contain positive integers smaller than X(eg: 3). Should I add Y>0 after X>Y ?

Comment: You can't say, `X>Y` unless both `X` and `Y` are already bound. So doing `Y>0` after won't eliminate the error. I think you need to rephrase your question, since it says, "...a programme list(X,Y) to check whether all the elements in list Y are smaller than X." which is what your existing predicate correctly does. Do you want your list to be a random sequence, or a consecutive sequence, 1, 2, ..., X-1?

Comment: a consecutive sequence

Comment: In the `greater` example, you've given it instantiated information. You are checking existing values. If you want to compare apples to apples, try `greater(3, X, Y)` which will fail for the same reason `list(3, Y)` fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since - judging from your comment - you seem to be reasoning over integers: That's a textbook example for using finite domain constraints, which are available in almost all modern Prolog implementations and generalize integer arithmetic so that you can use it in all directions.

Your code works exactly as expected with, among others, B-Prolog, GNU Prolog, SICStus, SWI and YAP if you just use the finite domain constraint `(#>)/2` instead of the lower-level arithmetic primitive `(>)/2`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list(X, []).
list(X, [Y|Z]):- X#>Y, list(X,Z).
```

Constraints allow you to use this predicate, which you can also express with `maplist/2` as in the queries below, in all directions:

```
?- maplist(#>(3), [1,2]).
true.

?- maplist(#>(X), [1,2]).
X in 3..sup.

?- maplist(#>(3), [A,B]).
A in inf..2,
B in inf..2.

?- maplist(#>(X), [Y,Z]).
Z#=<X+ -1,
Y#=<X+ -1.
```

Even the most general query, where none of the arguments is instantiated, gives useful answers:

```
?- maplist(#>(X), Ls).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [_G1022],
_G1022#=<X+ -1 ;
Ls = [_G1187, _G1190],
_G1190#=<X+ -1,
_G1187#=<X+ -1 ;
etc.
```

**EDIT**: Also the example you now added can be made much more general with finite domain constraints:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

greater(_, [], []).
greater(X, [H|Y], [H|Z]) :- H #> X, greater(X, Y, Z).
greater(X, [H|Y], Z) :- H #=< X, greater(X, Y, Z).
```

You can now use it in all directions, for example:

```
?- greater(X, [E], Ls).
Ls = [E],
X#=<E+ -1 ;
Ls = [],
X#>=E.
```

This is not possible with the original version, whose author may not have been aware of constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The error message does not appear now. What should I do next in order to have a result showing lists. For example, list(3,Y) returns Y = [], [1], [1,2] ...etc

Comment: To get concrete integers as solutions, you can use the built-in predicates `labeling/2` or `label/1`. For example: `?- list(3, Ls), Ls ins 0..sup, label(Ls).` Note though that you of course need further constraints to really describe *ascending* lists. The predicate `chain/2` that is available in SWI-Prolog may be useful for you. Example: `?- length(Ls, _), chain(Ls, #<).`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, but I am still confused about `X` and `Y` being unbound mentioned by mbratch in the previous comments. I have updated some information in my question.

Comment: @ipodtest: You can restrict the values even further. Say, `X in 1..3` meaning `X` is 1, 2, or 3.